# How to remove blue background on hover and on focus for select option

Tags: css, select, colors, hover

Not able to change the default blue background colour on hover of select option.

Tried css and HTML as below

```css
option:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

option:checked {
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option> AA</option>
  <option> BB</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually you can't unless you make a `ul` instead.

Comment: @SMAKSS I cant used UI  need to use select options only as this is for the chatbot. In chatbot HTML automatically rendered automatically by the framework. I just paste the example.

Comment: I don't think you could change this in macOS if you want to have a persistent look in all browsers/OS consider build a costume dropdown.

Comment: @AmirMeimari do you have sample code.

Comment: @Ameer There are lots of samples on the internet. take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: Thanks for sharing example @AmirMeimari, I am not able to add any class to select in HTML as I am using chatbot framework. In chatbot framework HTML code is rendered by framework automatically we don't have any access to HTML code. We can override their element by using css name .

Answer (score 0):

try to this,

```
select:focus{
  outline:0;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.